# prevent load master page content on each post back or page load after login

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, postback, menuitem

I have a master page on which I have a menu.C# code for menu is in an user control which created at run time with user permission stored in DB.
currently on each page request or post back menu is created. As menu creation uses a DB call

My concern is this that Can I prevent this DB call on each request?
means when user first time logged in I will do a DB call for user's permission and menu will be created after that for every request or post back no DB call for Menu.

Will output cache for menu user control work for my scenario?

Comment: !isPostback  write ur usercontrol code here

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Page.IsPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx) property in your page_load method.

For example:

```
private void Page_Load()
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // Do anything here you want to only happen when 
        // the page is loaded 1st time
        // such as hit the database for the menu...
        CreateMenu();
    }
}
```

If you make your menu into a user control you can use caching (by param) to cache each user's menu, but only add this after you've tested the logic because debugging when you've got caching on can be tricky.

**Edit - response to comment**
Create your menu as a user control and then use [control output caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx#aspnet-cachingtechniquesbestpract_topic3), to ensure it is created for your users when they log in and held in cache after that. If your menu doesn't change during the duration of your users visit then  you can have quite an aggressive cache, otherwise if your menu needs to respond to changes made (perhaps an admin granting the user another menu item) then you could cache until changes are detected in the database.

Also see the MSDN documentation on [Caching portions of a ASP.NET Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h30h475z.aspx) for some examples on how to achieve partial page output caching

Comment: Hi Simon, this will work only in case when page is post back. My concern is I want to create menu only once when user logged in after that on page load or post back of any page I don't want to re-create menu.

Comment: Hi Rajesh, I have edited my answer to give some suggestions on partial page output caching that may help achieve what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

You can store a check in the session variable itself during the login.

Every time the page gets loaded you just need to check the session variable.

Please let me know if you have issues.

Answer (score 0):

One more thing i can suggest which i had done in my web application . I have put that whole menu related information in session at the time of login and then in master page from that session i have taken menu related information rather than going for a trip of database everytime..